# How to set properties of an object, for which Xcode is unaware exist, but do

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, properties

Edit - I've revised to clarify.

```
//myViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) SCDataObject *dataObject;
```

In storyboard, I've created a single VC with the custom class myViewController.  I've given it the storyboard ID myViewControllerStoryboardId.

```
//anotherClass.m 
UIViewController *viewController = 
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];
```

I instantiate the custom VC, but notice I'm setting it to a pointer of type UIViewController **on purpose** for a few reasons.

```
//anotherClass.m
//I want to set the property, dataObject, of the instantiated VC, but this doesn't work.
viewController.dataObject = something;
```

The actual object has the property, but the pointer to it is of a different class.  How do I set the property?

Comment: Share the "few reasons" - otherwise this scenario does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your viewcontrollers class. I used `MyViewController`, just replace it with your class name. Here is the code:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
...
MyViewController *viewController = 
      [self.storyboard 
                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];

//It works!
viewController.dataObject = something;
```

EDIT:
If you really don't want to use your custom class, give this code a shot:

```
[viewController setValue:something forKey:@"dataObject"];
```

But i can't think of a reason for doing this.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware, but don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if myViewController is a subclass of UIViewController then you should really do:

```
myViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];
```

You also need to make sure that you change the class of your custom UIViewController in your Storyboard from the generic UIViewController to myViewController (select your VC in the StoryBoard and then go to the "Identity Inspector", that is the 3rd tab, in the right-hand Utilities screen. You can change there the class of the custom VC to your subclass).

**Update after Question Edit:**

The UIViewController class is part of UIKit. Anytime you need to customize a VC beyond what can be done in SB, you need to subclass UIViewController (and create a custom VC). So if you are trying to have a custom property (dataObject) of a UIVC without subclassing UIVC, the answer is you can't.

Having said that, maybe the question is not fully clear. If you are looking to have a subclass of UIVC with a property dataObject but with multiple instances of that subclass; you can always create that subclass once and then have multiple instances of that class that you would give different names so:

```
myViewController* viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];
myViewController* viewController2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];
myViewController* viewController3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];
```

They will all be different instances of the same subclass (myViewController) and the values of the dataObject will be distinct for each instance. In other words, you can set:

```
viewController1.dataObject=someObject;
viewController2.dataObject=anotherObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get warnings, but this should work for setting:

```
[viewController setDataObject:something];
```

And this for getting:

```
[viewController dataObject];
```

To avoid a crash, you probably would do something like this:

```
if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setDataObject:)])
{
    [viewController setDataObject:something];
}
```

Comment: How did you add dataObject to the generic UIVC class?

Comment: I didn't, that's why you get a warning about "UIViewController may not respond to "setDataObject".  If you do this, you probably want to check that it will respond to the selector or else you will crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you just type `viewController` as `id`, though you still can't use the property directly, you could send it a message the corresponds to that property, without warnings. You could use respondsToSelector: to see if it supports the accessor function for that property.

```
id viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];

if( [viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setDataObject:)] ) {
    [viewController setDataObject:something];
}
```

Personally, I would probably just:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerStoryboardId"];

viewController.dataObject = something;
```